# Low frame rate in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, camera, frame-rate

I have a blender obj. file in an OpenGL application. I have also added a camera so that it will move in around that object (it's a building, so it's pretty large). The frame rate on it is awful.

Why is it slow and/or how can I make it faster?

```
void camera (void) {
glRotatef(xrot,1.0,0.0,0.0);  
glRotatef(yrot,0.0,1.0,0.0);  
glTranslated(-xpos,-ypos,-zpos); }
```

This is just my simple camera class. Just in case it helps.

Comment: This question is more than likely unanswerable (besides random guesses) without seeing your code.

Comment: @Bart He is using the fixed function pipeline, you can see it with the few lines above. That has a big performance impact. See my answer.

Comment: @FelixK. Your answer perfectly aligns with my "besides some random guesses". Educated guesses, but random ones.

Comment: @Bart The question isn't really good but at least he has something he can start with and if this isn't helping ( i'm sure it will ) he can ask here again.

Comment: That isn't really a camera class, but a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some reasons your code might be slow:

- You aren't using [VertexBuffer](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) objects
- You are using the [fixed function pipeline](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and not [shaders](http://www.clockworkcoders.com/oglsl/tutorials.html)
- You aren't optimizing your drawing code that only areas are rendered which are visible ( look a.e. for [bsp-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) )

After all you've a lot of optimizations to do. I would start with optimizing my render pipeline and remove the fixed function pipeline and start to use shaders and vertex-buffers.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. i wasnt looking for a direct code statement, more information on how frame rates can be improved. i just phrased the question poorly. thank you for the help though. i have integrated vertex buffering and it is going alot quicker. much appreciated!

Comment: @user1956870 Happy that i could help.